# select time from column have datetime format with sql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

Here is mysql data

```
--
-- Table structure for table `pending_accounts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pending_accounts` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `jdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Pending accounts' AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `pending_accounts`
--

INSERT INTO `pending_accounts` (`id`, `username`, `jdate`) VALUES
(3, 'admin', '2013-04-26 01:57:24');
```

and my php and sql code

```
$last_update = time();  // for example 1367022789


 $q = $db->fetchOne("SELECT * FROM pending_accounts WHERE '".strtotime(jdate)."' < '".$last_update."' ORDER BY id ASC");
```

As you can see i'm trying to select all pending accounts where jdate < $last_update
and $last_update is time() numberic format like '1367022789' , so i have used strtotime() to change jdate which have datetime format like '2013-04-26 01:57:24' to numburic format.

and unfortunately this doesn't work correctly.

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is invalid:

```
'".strtotime(jdate)."' < '".$last_update."'
```

You're trying to convert a constant to a timestamp like this.

You probably intend to use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function in mysql.

```
"SELECT * FROM pending_accounts WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`jdate`) < '".$last_update."' ORDER BY id ASC"
```